# Pygameでrect.centerで幅500高さ187の画像を500x500ウィンドウの真ん中に表示したい。

Tags: python, pygame

とても長いので一部抜粋ですが、タイトル通り
Pygameでrect.centerで幅500高さ187の画像を500x500ウィンドウの真ん中に表示したい。
のですが良い案が浮かばずあまりプログラミング知識も浅いため検索もできず
困っています。どうしたらよいでしょうか？

```
#ゲームオーバー画面の表示について
   if gameover:
       mixer.music.load('musics/carcrush.wav')
       mixer.music.play()
       
       screen.blit(crash, crash_rect)

       
       gvgamen = pygame.image.load("gameovermoto2-3.png")
       gvgamen_rect = gvgamen.get_rect()
       gvgamen_rect.center = ("")
       screen.blit(gvgamen, gvgamen_rect)
       

   pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: こちらの記事が参考になるのでは？ [How to center an image in the middle of the window in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70530062/9014308)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gvgamen_rect.center`を`screen.get_rect().center`に合わせることで画像の中央をスクリーンの中央に合わせることができます。

ご質問のコードにある`gvgamen_rect.center = ("")`を、`gvgamen_rect.center = screen.get_rect().center`に変更してください。

**サンプルコード**

```
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
gvgamen = pygame.image.load("gameovermoto2-3.png")

while True:
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    # 画面中央に画像を描画する
    gvgamen_rect = gvgamen.get_rect()
    gvgamen_rect.center = screen.get_rect().center
    screen.blit(gvgamen, gvgamen_rect)
    # 画面中央に画像を描画するワンライナーのコード(上の3行のコードと同等)
    #screen.blit(gvgamen, gvgamen.get_rect(center = screen.get_rect().center))

    pygame.display.update()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```